# Facing problem in running venv in Vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I run the following command in my vs code terminal

```
python -m venv venv
```

after this when I open new terminal I am getting following error..

[image]

```
PS E:\Llama Code\llama> & "e:/Llama Code/llama/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
& : File E:\Llama Code\llama\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "e:/Llama Code/llama/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

How to solve this. I want to run virtual environment in my vs code.

I tried to run virtual environment in my vs code but couldn't do that.

Comment: You need to allow the execution of powershell scripts, which is blocked by default. You can use `Set-ExecutionPolicy undefined` in an administrator powershell terminal, but you should note the security risks it presents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+Activate.ps1+cannot+be+loaded+because+running+scripts+is+disabled+on+this+system

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows PowerShell with the "Run as Administrator" option.

Type in:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

The above command will allow running unsigned scripts.